# get multiple value from json and save them in model

Tags: python

In `json` I have a bunch of bullets like this

```
{'Bullet 1': 'Made from high gloss polypropylene', 'Bullet 2': 'Card pocket for personalisation on front of wallet', 'Bullet 3': 'Additional pocket on rear of wallet', 'Bullet 4': 'Stud closure to keep contents secure', 'Bullet 5': 'Colour: Blue', 'Bullet 6':}
```

After iteration and cleanup of the `json` I want to save all Bullet's in one model filed, right now I'm saving only one

```
for _product in json_obj:
    Product.objects.update_or_create(
        ...
        # save all BUllet ???
        bullet=_product['Bullet 1'],
        ...
     )
```

How can I fetch all of them and save them into my model field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need pass 1 value each iteration you can do the follow, if you need give to Product.objects.update_or_create() a list of values or more values all together the code change a bit.

```
json_obj = {'Bullet 1': 'Made from high gloss polypropylene', 'Bullet 2': 'Card pocket for personalisation on front of wallet', 'Bullet 3': 'Additional pocket on rear of wallet', 'Bullet 4': 'Stud closure to keep contents secure', 'Bullet 5': 'Colour: Blue', 'Bullet 6':'test'}
for i in json_obj .keys():
    print json_obj [i]
    Product.objects.update_or_create(json_obj [i])
```

I printed for let u see what get in each loop:

```
Made from high gloss polypropylene
Card pocket for personalisation on front of wallet
Additional pocket on rear of wallet
Stud closure to keep contents secure
Colour: Blue
test
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I need to do more, will leave it as it is it's a good example, I'll ask another Q.